# #1064 Syntax Error : In "Update Query"

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use this mysql code

```
update catalog_product_entity_decimal
  set value = "6.0000" 
  where attribute_id = 75 and
        entity_in ( SELECT 
        product_id 
        from `catalog_category_product` 
        WHERE category_id =37 );
```

i'm getting this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT product_id from `catalog_category_product` ' at line 4
```

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my query. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the IN clause after entity_in. Use this:

```
update catalog_product_entity_decimal
  set value = "6.0000" 
  where attribute_id = 75 and
        entity_id IN ( SELECT 
        product_id 
        from `catalog_category_product` 
        WHERE category_id =37 );
```

Comment: Or it should be `entity in`.

Comment: Thankyou. Your code fixed my issue. But its `entity_id IN` instead of `entity_in IN`

Comment: @Giri thats because I did not know your column names. Anyways, I will fix it in the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think catalog_category_product will not contain the ' symbol.
Try the query without using the ' symbol

Answer (score 1):

You missed `=` OR `in` in the query